# When I replace XML DOM with some HTML and inject some js, the js doesn’t run

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I’m trying to make a bookmarklet that swaps out the DOM on the current page for a new one, and then injects and runs some javascript.

It works fine when the original page is HTML (so I don’t think this is a CORS problem). However, when the original page is XML, the injected javascript doesn’t run :( Why not? How can I get it working?

Here’s some example bookmarklet code:

```js
(function () {
  var jsHref = 'https://rawgit.com/andylolz/b2e894fa5ccdecacd901c05769fa97fe/raw/289719871f859a1b19e06f8b8ce3769f0002ce55/js.js';
  var htmlHref = 'https://rawgit.com/andylolz/b2e894fa5ccdecacd901c05769fa97fe/raw/289719871f859a1b19e06f8b8ce3769f0002ce55/html.html';

  // fetch some HTML
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', htmlHref, false);
  xhr.send();
  var htmlString = xhr.response;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var result = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

  // swap the DOM for the fetched HTML
  document.replaceChild(document.adoptNode(result.documentElement), document.documentElement);

  // inject some javascript
  var sc = document.createElement('script');
  sc.setAttribute('src', jsHref);
  document.documentElement.appendChild(sc);
})();
```

Here it is working on codepen (on an HTML page):
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEWemL?editors=1010

Again – If I run the above on an XML page, it mostly works, but the injected javascript doesn’t execute.

Thanks!